# Compare datetime to 7days ago on Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

We are trying to display the machine data.
So, We created Visualforce Page to search machine.
Customer want to see which machine isn't working.
  1. If machine's Last-Working-Datetime is NULL, this field's background-color is gray.
  2. If 7days passed from machine's Last-Working-Datetime, this field's background-color is red.

We can create 1.
But can't create 2.

first error

> The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>'

We changed to check null.

second error

> Incorrect argument type for operator '-'.

Please help us.
What should I do?

Visualforce

```
    <apex:page controller="SearchSampleListController" action="{!init}" 　readOnly="true">
<apex:outputpanel>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageblockTable id="resultTable" value="{!result}" var="o" frame="box">

                <!--normal-->
                <apex:column style="width:80px;" rendered="{!o.LastWorkDatetime__c != null}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Last Work{!IF(sortKey == 'LastWorkDatetime__c', sortOrder, '　')}">
                            <apex:param value="LastWorkDatetime__c" name="String" assignTo="{!sortingField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField style="width:80px;" value="{!o.LastWorkDatetime__c}"/>
                </apex:column>


                 <!--null-->
                <apex:column style="width:80px;background-color:#ffebcd;" rendered="{!o.LastWorkDatetime__c == null}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Last Work{!IF(sortKey == 'LastWorkDatetime__c', sortOrder, '　')}">
                            <apex:param value="LastWorkDatetime__c" name="String" assignTo="{!sortingField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField style="width:80px;" value="{!o.LastWorkDatetime__c}"/>
                </apex:column>


                <!--＊＊＊＊ERROR＊＊＊＊-->
                <!--Incorrect argument type for operator '-'.-->
                <apex:column style="width:80px;background-color:red;" rendered="{!If(AND(NOT(ISBLANK (o.LastWorkDatetime__c)),o.LastWorkDatetime__c - sevenDaysAgo > 7),true,false)}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Last Work{!IF(sortKey == 'LastWorkDatetime__c', sortOrder, '　')}">
                            <apex:param value="LastWorkDatetime__c" name="String" assignTo="{!sortingField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField style="width:80px;" value="{!o.LastWorkDatetime__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageblockTable>


        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputpanel>
</apex:page>
```

Apex class

```
public with sharing class SearchSampleListController {
    public Datetime sevenDaysAgo { get;set; }                // criterion

    /**
* init
*/
    public void init(){

        this.sevenDaysAgo = Datetime.newInstance(Date.today().addDays(-7),Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0));
        this.result = new List<Sample__c>();
        search();
    }


    /**
* search
* this is sample
*/
    public PageReference search() {
        this.result = [SELECT Name, LastWorkDatetime__c FROM Sample__c ];

        return null;
    }    
}
```

Comment: 2 suggestions: Remove the space between ISBLANK and (o.LastWorkDatetime__c) and have you tried wrapping the subtraction in a parenthesis? (o.LastWorkDateTime__c - sevenDaysAgo) > 7?.....Also, have you checked that both variables are DateTime?

Comment: I tried this.  But, console's Problem occurred....
  
「Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Object」
`rendered="{!If(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(o.LastAuthenticatedDate__c)),(o.LastAuthenticatedDate__c - sevenDaysAgo)>7),true,false)}"`

Comment: What kind of field is "LastAuthenticatedDate__c"?

Comment: LastAuthenticatedDate__c is date/time field.